# Not able to add a library to project in the Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm already facing this error:

> "Failed to
>   resolve:com.github.ygorbarboza:AKParallax-Android:fce9eac521"
>
> "Showing error :Gradle DSL method not found:'maven()' "

Here's my `build.gradle` file.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhishek.experiment"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.ygorbarboza:AKParallax-Android:fce9eac521'

}
```

I have even added the repository

```
repositories {
   maven {
      url "https://jitpack.io"
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image, if you use image instead of your *real code* we'll not be able to copy-paste, run, and debug it.

Comment: I have added the code , please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1056)

Comment: copy paste the complete gradle file so that we can have a proper look where its going wrong

Comment: Where have you added the repository?